# Write formula to Excel with Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am in the process of brain storming how to best tackle the below problem. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Sample Excel sheet columns:

```
Column A  |  Column B  | Column C
Apple     |  Apple     |
Orange    |  Orange    |
Pear      |  Banana    |
```

I want Excel to tell me whether items in column A and B match or mismatch and display results in column C. The formula I enter in column C would be `=IF(A1=B1, "Match", "Mismatch")`

On excel, I would just drag the formula to the rest of the cells in column C to apply the formula to them and the result would be:

```
Column A  |  Column B  | Column C
Apple     |  Apple     | Match
Orange    |  Orange    | Match
Pear      |  Banana    | Mismatch
```

To automate this using a python script, I tried:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
Sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
for cellObj in Sheet.columns[2]:
    cellObj.value = '=IF($A$1=$B$1, "Match", "Mismatch")
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

This wrote the formula to all cells in column C, however the formula only referenced cell A1 and B1, so result in all cells in column C = Match.

```
Column A  |  Column B  | Column C
Apple     |  Apple     | Match
Orange    |  Orange    | Match
Pear      |  Banana    | Match
```

How would you handle this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You probably want to make the creation of the formula dynamic so each row of `C` takes from the corresponding rows of `A` and `B`:

```
for i, cellObj in enumerate(Sheet.columns[2], 1):
    cellObj.value = '=IF($A${0}=$B${0}, "Match", "Mismatch")'.format(i)
```

Comment: sorry to reup an old post, but someone [referred to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45133245/write-formula-to-excel-with-python-error), openpyxl has changed, or i missed  something ?

Comment: @PRMoureu Not sure about that, but going by the linked post, it is most likely so.

Answer (score 10):

fortunately now you can easy do formulas in certain records. Also there are simpler functions to use, such as:

1. `wb.sheetnames` instead of `wb.read_sheet_names()`
2. `sheet = wb['SHEET_NAME']` instead of `sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('SHEET_NAME')`

**And formulas can be easily inserted with:**

`sheet['A1'] = '=SUM(1+1)'`