# Write formula to Excel with Python error

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I try to follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195957/write-formula-to-excel-with-python) to add some formula in my excel using python and openpyxl package.

That link is what i need for my task.

but in this code :

```
for i, cellObj in enumerate(Sheet.columns[2], 1):
    cellObj.value = '=IF($A${0}=$B${0}, "Match", "Mismatch")'.format(i)
```

i take an error at `Sheet.columns[2]` any idea why ? i follow the complete code.

i have python 2.7.13 version if that helps for this error.

****UPDATE****

COMPLETE CODE :

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test1.xlsx')
print wb.get_sheet_names()
Sheet = wb.worksheets[0]
for i, cellObj in enumerate(Sheet.columns[2], 1):
    cellObj.value = '=IF($A${0}=$B${0}, "Match", "Mismatch")'.format(i)
```

error message :

```
for i, cellObj in enumerate(Sheet.columns[2], 1):
```

> TypeError: 'generator' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Comment: Did you name 'Sheet' the variable referring to  the sheet ?

Comment: @PRMoureu is `'Sheet'` simple like question link `Sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')`

Comment: can you please add the exact error you got, and the code could help too if you can update your post

Comment: @PRMoureu  i have update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ws.columns` and `ws.rows` are properties that return generators. But openpyxl also supports [slicing and indexing for rows and columns](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#accessing-many-cells)

So, `ws['C']` will give a list of the cells in the third column.

Answer (score 3):

For other Stack adventurers looking to copy/paste a formula:

```
# Writing from pandas back to an existing EXCEL workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename=myfilename, read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
ws = wb['Mysheetname']

# Paste a formula Vlookup!  Look at column A, put result in column AC.

for i, cellObj in enumerate(ws['AC'], 1):
    cellObj.value = "=VLOOKUP($A${0}, 'LibrarySheet'!C:D,2,FALSE)".format(i)
```

One issue, I have a header and the formula overwrites it.  Anyone know how to start from row 2?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start from another row you can either use an if statement to skip the first row, or specify the range in the enumeration. A coded example is below:

```
wb = load_workbook(filename=myfilename, read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
ws = wb['Mysheetname']

# using an if statement
for i, cellObj in enumerate(ws['AC'], 1):
    if i > 1: 
        cellObj.value = "=VLOOKUP($A${0}, 'LibrarySheet'!C:D,2,FALSE)".format(i)

# specifying range, up to max row on worksheet - or you can specify an exact range
for i, cellObj in enumerate(ws['AC2:AC'+str(ws.max_row)],2):
    cellObj[0].value = "=VLOOKUP($A${0}, 'LibrarySheet'!C:D,2,FALSE)".format(i)
```

The second method requires you to begin the index at 2 and returns a tuple rather than a cell object, so you need to specify cellObj[0].value to return the value of the cell object.

Answer (score 1):

fortunately now you can easy do formulas in certain records. Also there are simpler functions to use, such as:

1. `wb.sheetnames` instead of `wb.read_sheet_names()`
2. `sheet = wb['SHEET_NAME']` instead of `sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('SHEET_NAME')`

**And formulas can be easily inserted with:**

`sheet['A1'] = '=SUM(1+1)'`