# Increment formula written to excel with Python

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

The script below reads in multiple csv files, merges some and writes them to an Excel file in two different sheets.

It also adds this formula (`=IF(COUNTIFS(Meds!A:A,B2)>0,1,0)`) to the last column in every cell in the Meds column, but I need it to increment, so the second cell would be `=IF(COUNTIFS(Meds!A:A,B3)>0,1,0)` and so on. I can't figure out how to write a loop which will do this. I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195957/write-formula-to-excel-with-python) but I have issues using openpyxl, so would like to avoid that library.

```
import pandas as pd

# read in multiple csv files 
df1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv", encoding = 'utf-8')
df2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv", encoding = 'utf-8')
meds = pd.read_csv("meds.csv", encoding = 'utf-8')

# create a list of dataframes (excluding meds)
dfs = [df1, df2]

# merge dataframes in list
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='RecordKey'), dfs)

# add empty column
df_final["Meds"] = ""

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('final.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# add formula to Meds
df_final['Meds'] = '=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,E2)>0,1,0)'

# write to csv
df_final.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Combined')
meds.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Meds')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop and string formatting to create a list of formulas that can be inserted into your `df`.

```
length_of_df = len(df)
list_of_formulas = []

for i in range(2,length_of_df+2):
    formula = '=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,E{0}>0,1,0)'.format(i)
    list_of_formulas.append(formula)

# print(list_of_formulas)

# ['=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,E2>0,1,0)',
# '=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,E3>0,1,0)',   
# '=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,E4>0,1,0)',    
# '=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,E5>0,1,0)', 
# '=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,E6>0,1,0)']

# Assign list of formulas to df
df.loc[:, "Meds"] = list_of_formulas
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Now I just need to loop through the list and add each formula to the appropriate cell.

Comment: @n8_ My understanding is that these formulas will basically become a single column in a single dataframe, is that correct?

Comment: Yup, that's correct. I'm just new to Python so I'm trying to figure out how to add this list to the desired column. I tried `df_final['Meds'] = list_of_formulas` but got a `Length of values does not match length of index` error

Comment: @n8_ Okay, that's because the length of the list and the length of `df` are not the same. I adjusted the range to correspond to the cell numbers in your example but I will edit my answer so that does not occur. You may need to fiddle with the range so that the cell number in the formula corresponds to the actual cell number

Comment: So I already changed `length_of_df` to `len(df_final.index)`. When I print out the list of formulas, I get 7763, which is the total number of rows in my dataframe. But I assume since this didn't work I still have something wrong?

Comment: @n8_ we can continue the discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) if you'd like.