# Write python list of formulas to excel

Tags: python, excel, list, formula

My script reads in multiple `.csv` files into dataframes, adds all to a list of dataframes and merges them on `RecordKey`.

```
import pandas as pd
demoRaw = pd.read_csv("D2.csv", encoding = 'utf-8')
keyRaw = pd.read_csv("Key.csv", encoding = 'utf-8')
vitalRaw = pd.read_csv("V2.csv", encoding = 'utf-8')

dfs = [key, demo, vital, dx]

df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='Key'), dfs)
```

Then I add an empty column called Meds

```
df_final["Meds"] = ""
```

Create Excel writer

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('final.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
```

Assign length of df and create empty list for formulas

```
length_of_df = len(df_final)
list_of_formulas = []
```

This loop (credit to W.Dodge) iterates the formula to match the cell

```
for i in range(2,length_of_df+2):
    formula = '=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,A{0})>0,1,0)'.format(i)
    list_of_formulas.append(formula)
```

Then I try to write the list to the Meds column

```
df_final.loc[:, "Meds"] = list_of_formulas

df_final.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Combined')
meds.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Meds')

writer.save()
```

However, Excel returns the following error messages:

[image]

Selecting no returns an empty workbook. Selecting Yes returns...

[image]

Everything else is merged fine, but the Meds column is filled with 0s, no formulas.

Log file listing repairs:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><logFileName>error133040_01.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\Users\4469177\Nate\Work\Coding\Python\scripts\final.xlsx'</summary><removedRecords summary="Following is a list of removed records:"><removedRecord>Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part</removedRecord></removedRecords></recoveryLog>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your formula. You credited W.Dodge, which is clearly referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53510429/95852). But notice the formula in your [*question*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53509647/95852):

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Meds!A:A,B2)>0,1,0)
```

Notice the paren which closes COUNTIFS.

Comment: nice catch but still receiving the same error and issue.

Comment: But you put the closing paren in the wrong place. It's still not a valid formula.

Comment: That was it, thanks! The formula doesn't work but at least it's being populated in Excel properly

Comment: Had another error in my sheetname, everything else is working great. Thanks again!