# insert a excel formula in whole column python

Tags: python, excel

I m working on some project where I want to insert an excel formula in a particular column in an existing workbook sheet.

I need to show the formula in the excel file of a particular cell (for example if someone clicks on cell A1 and there is a formula of (V lookup) it should show that formula)

I tried with `xlsxwritter` but I am not getting them the accurate result.

Any piece of code or any approach on this

Comment: Excel doesn't, to the best of my knowledge, have a method for doing this in the file format at all.  It allows you to fill down into all the cells in the active worksheet, but it doesn't quite allow what you're looking for.  You can't make Python do something Excel can't do natively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write formula to Excel with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195957/write-formula-to-excel-with-python)

Comment: thanks, @DylanBrams but that code I already tried that is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```
    import openpyxl 
    i=1
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook() 
    sheet = wb.active
    for i, cellObj in enumerate(Sheet['D'], 1): #assuming you will need to 
         cellObj.value = '=IF(OR(B2 ="rj", B2 ="rj1", B2 ="rj2"),rj)'

    wb.save("yourfile.xlsx")
```

Comment: As far as I understood the question, the OP wants to put a formula text of `vlookup` in one the workbook cells.

Comment: thanks for your code but it is not working actually there is "If condition" code which I had to run in the whole column like "IF(OR(B2 ="rj", B2 ="rj1", B2 ="rj2"),rj) " something like this

Comment: As I understand it, when a user clicks into a cell in a column, he wants that cell to be pre-filled with a formula.  Which implies that you have a formula bound to an entire column.  Maybe that solves the question as asked, but if that is the case this is a duplicate question.

Comment: @ROHITJHA: Can you update the question with your exact ask?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal actually I want to fill the column with excel formula using python

Comment: yes this I want but it should be applied in the whole column A

Comment: Loop while loop little less for testing purpose. Lets say 5 or 10. Then see

Comment: i came to arise with a new problem now to update formula according to cell

Comment: so instead of `B2` everywhere you need B3, B4...so on according to cell ?