# Working with excel functions and openpyxl python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I am generating excel spreadsheets with python using openpyxl.

Currently I am trying to write a function to an entire column in one of the sheets.

The code I currently am using works fine, there is just the issue of it inputs the function exactly as written. I am trying to use VLookups and need each new function added to have the cell reference incremented.

Here is current code

```
"""Add formula columns"""

#first new column 
#load workbook 
book = load_workbook('export1.xlsx')
#Assign sheet
sheet = book['RAW DATA']

for cell in sheet['V']: #loop through all cells in column 
    cell.value = '=VLOOKUP(N2,Matrix!L:M,2,FALSE)' #and assign function

#name the column
sheet['V1'] = 'New Column'

#save & close
book.save('testing.xlsx')
book.close()
```

The Vlookup starts with cell reference "N2" ('=VLOOKUP(**N2**,Matrix!L:M,2,FALSE)') I am looking to increment it each time the function is added. So the next cell would have **N3** referenced, then **N4** after that, and **N5** after that and so one and so forth.

Any insights or advice would be a great help.

I tried this but for some reason the incrementation is not working

```
"""Add formula columns"""

#first new column 
#load workbook 
book = load_workbook('export1.xlsx')
#Assign sheet
sheet = book['RAW DATA']

part1 = "=vlookup(N"
part2 = 2
part3 = ",Matrix!L:M,2,FALSE)"
vlookup = part1 + str(part2) + part3
stringvlookup = str(vlookup)

for cell in sheet['V']: #loop through all cells in column 
    cell.value = stringvlookup #and assign function
    part2 += 1


#name the column
sheet['V1'] = 'New Column'

#save & close
book.save('testing.xlsx')
book.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write formula to Excel with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195957/write-formula-to-excel-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
# using an if statement
for i, cellObj in enumerate(sheet['V'], 1):
    if i > 1: 
        cellObj.value = "=VLOOKUP($N${0},Matrix!L:M,2,FALSE)".format(i)
```