# Excel formula formats from Python to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a problem exporting Pandas data to excel:
I want, for example to export a data like this

```
= 1+2+3
```

Now, to do this, I tried two ways:

```
d = p.DataFrame({'test1': ["=1+2+3"], 'test2': ["'=1+2+3"]})
d.to_excel('test3.xlsx')
```

Excel dispays the column this way:

```
test1 test2
6     '=1+2+3
```

Fo test2, I though excel would ignore the ', and consider the formula as a text, what I want. But it displays it. Do you know how could I do?

Thanks for help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write formula to Excel with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195957/write-formula-to-excel-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using **[openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html)** library (which comes with pandas module).

Here is a small example:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# If you want to open an exisiting file you can use instead: 
# wb = load_workbook(r'test3.xlsx')

# Add value to cell
ws['A1'] = "test1"
ws['B1'] = "test2"
ws['C1'] = "Total"

# Add formula to cell
ws['A2'] = "=2+3+4"
ws['B2'] = "=1+2+3"
ws['C2'] = "=SUM(A2:B2)"

# To add the Formula string to a cell just change the data_type of that cell
ws['D2'] = "=SUM(A2:B2)"
ws['D2'].data_type = 's'

# Save file
wb.save(r'./test3.xlsx')

# Close
wb.close()
```

Here's a [guide](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html) on how to append a panda dataframe to an excel sheet using **Openpyxl**

Comment: The formula is not visible as a string when we open the excel file. Excel still evaluates it as a regular formula and displays the result, not the formula itself.

Comment: Great! It works perfectly well now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html)

It provides an option to stop Excel from evaluating the formula string, so the formula string will appear as it is.
Here is a simple example.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx', {'strings_to_formulas': False,}) #Specify not to convert string to formulas

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write_string('A1', "= {} + {} + {}".format(1, 2, 3))


workbook.close()
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output: Formula string (text)]

Check the usage of xlswriter with pandas [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html)