# I can't insert a formula into an Excel table using pyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am currently trying to insert three formulas (shown below) into a range of cells in an excel table. However, this is not working and I have had a number of different issues came up including (but not limited too), no formula being written at all, multiple functions gaining a @ symbol at the from (e.g. INDIRECT -> @INDIRECT) and all cc

```
Formula # - Formula - Cells which will get the formula
Formula 1 - =INDEX(INDIRECT("Table3[Return Value]"), IFNA(MATCH(1,COUNTIF([@Description],"*" &INDIRECT("Table3[Component Name]")&"*"),0),MATCH("Z-N/A",INDIRECT("Table3[Return Value]"),0))) -B11:B11+n
Formula 2 - =ROW([@[Line Number]])-ROW(Table1[[#Headers],[Line Number]]) - C11:C11+n
Formula 3 - =IF(LEFT([@Value],3)="DNF",0,IF([@Designator]="",0,LEN([@Designator])-LEN(SUBSTITUTE([@Designator],",",""))+1)) - E11:E11+n
```

The code I am using to insert the code is shown below. I am using openpyxl.

```
def saveDataColumn2(workbook, column, length, data):
    sheet = workbook['Issue _']
    
    for i in range(length):
        cellID = column + str(11+i)
        sheet[cellID] = data

quantityFormula = '=IF(LEFT([@Value],3)="DNF",0,IF([@Designator]="",0,LEN([@Designator])-LEN(SUBSTITUTE([@Designator],",",""))+1))'
length = 10

saveDataColumn2(workbook, 'E', length, quantityFormula)
```

I have tried multiple things to try and fix this none of which have worked. I have tried using
ArrayFormula
DataTableFormula
I have rewrote the function so it was all indirects (this works but the table name had to be hard coded for the row columns, [@Value] became INDIRECT("Table1[@Value]"), which isn't feasible as the table number is going to change (Table 3, is an exception, its name will not change

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write formula to Excel with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195957/write-formula-to-excel-with-python)